# Android location app only running properly after clean install

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-gps, google-location-services

I wrote this app for an assignment, but for some reason two of the questions will only run properly once, and only after the app is installed.

e.g. If i install the app and run Question 1a then it will work perfectly. If I try and run Question 2 after that, or run Question 1a again, it won't work unless I uninstall and reinstall the apk. It also works the other way around, so if I run Question 2 first then Question 1a won't work and Question 2 won't work if I try and run it again.

I don't get any errors or crashes, it just doesn't do anything. It's strange though because Question 1b works perfectly all the time and is very similar to both Question 1a and Question 2 except it uses a Google Map.

Edit: I just realized that the map in question 1b doesn't work anymore (Google Maps API authorization failed) but it does update the address properly in the TextView, now if only I could figure out why the TextView updates in Question 1b but not the other two.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The code is as follows:

Question 1a:

```
public class Question1a extends FragmentActivity implements 
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{

private TextView txtAddress;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
public static final int REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1a);
    txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressEdit);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkPermissions();
    }
}

//creates a location request object and sets the location request intervals
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
{
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{

}

//Gets address and displays it in a TextView
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try
    {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(addresses == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No address found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);

        String finalAddress = "Address: ";
        for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        {
            finalAddress = finalAddress + address.getAddressLine(i);
        }
        txtAddress.setText(finalAddress);
    }
}

//build the API client
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    client.connect();
}

//Checks if the app has the required permissions to run (Location permissions)
public boolean checkPermissions()
{
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //permission has been granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    //if client is null(there is no Google API Client) this calls the method to build the Google API Client
                    if (client == null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions were denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}
}
```

Question 1b:

```
public class Question1b extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener
{

private TextView txtAddress;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location lastLocation;
private Marker currentLocationMarker;
public static final int REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1b);
    txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationAddressEdit);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkPermissions();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //permission has been granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    //if client is null(there is no Google API Client) this calls the method to build the Google API Client
                    if (client == null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions were denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}

//if the app has the right permissions then it will build the API client and enable location services when the map is ready
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

//creates a location request object and sets the location request intervals
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
{
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{

}

//Moves the marker when location changes
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    lastLocation = location;

    if (currentLocationMarker != null)
    {
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Location");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

    currentLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try
    {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(addresses == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No address found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);

        String finalAddress = "Address: ";
        for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        {
            finalAddress = finalAddress + address.getAddressLine(i);
        }
        txtAddress.setText(finalAddress);
    }
}

//Checks if the app has the required permissions to run (Location permissions & SMS permissions)
public boolean checkPermissions()
{
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

//build the API client
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    client.connect();
}
}
```

Question 2:

```
public class Question2 extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener
{

private TextView txtAddress;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;

public static final int REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE = 99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question2);
    txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.addressEdit);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
        checkPermissions();
    }
}

//creates a location request object and sets the location request intervals
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
{
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
{

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
{

}

//Gets address using geocoder and displays it in a TextView
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try
    {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(addresses == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No address found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String finalAddress = "Address: ";
        for (int i = 0; i <= address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        {
            finalAddress = finalAddress + address.getAddressLine(i);
        }
        txtAddress.setText(finalAddress);
    }
}

//build the API client
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    client.connect();
}

//Checks if the app has the required permissions to run (Location permissions & SMS permissions)
public boolean checkPermissions()
{
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        else
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);
        }
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                //permission has been granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    //if client is null(there is no Google API Client) this calls the method to build the Google API Client
                    if (client == null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions were denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }
}

public void sendMyLocation(View v)
{
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27718831284", null, "Your location is: " + txtAddress.getText(), null, null);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add logging to the `GoogleConnectionClient` callbacks like `onConnectionFailed` and `onConnectionSuspended` to verify that you are connected correctly.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I added logging to onConnectionFailed and onConnectionSuspended but I'm not seeing any messages in the logcat when I run the app